# The view doesn't work same name template in diffrence app

Tags: python, django

The two apps are in the one project

this is two apps tree

```
├─posts
│  ├─templates
│  │      modify.html
│  │      write.html
│
├─users
│  │
│  ├─templates
│  │      bookmark.html
│  │      index.html
│  │      modify.html
│  │      my_comment.html
│  │      my_posts.html
│  │      profile.html
│  │      signin.html
│  │      signup.html
```

My Project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'posts/',include('posts.urls')),
    url(r'users/',include('users.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in posts

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from posts.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',index,name='index'),
    url(r'^write',write,name='write'),
    url(r'^modify/$',post_modify,name='modify'),
]
```

urls.py in users

```
from posts.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',index,name='index'),
    url(r'^write',write,name='write'),
    url(r'^modify/$',post_modify,name='modify'),
]
```

views.py in posts

```
def post_modify(request):
    Postlist=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'modify.html',{'Postlist':Postlist})
```

views.py in users

```
def modify(request):
    Userlist=User.objects.all()
    return render(request,'modify.html',{'Ul':Userlist})
```

The views works but other views doesn't work related in modify.html

Comment: please improve your grammar and provide some code, your question is imcompreensible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django looks for template names in a sequential order through all your apps and uses the first match it finds.

You might have to rename the templates, to something like

posts_modify.html
user_modify.html

EDIT:

Alternative solution, restructure your templates.

make it such that you have posts/templates/posts/
and users/templates/users/

change posts view code to

```
def post_modify(request):
    Postlist=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,'posts/modify.html',{'Postlist':Postlist})
```

change users view code to

```
def modify(request):
    Userlist=User.objects.all()
    return render(request,'users/modify.html',{'Ul':Userlist})
```

Comment: if i make same name index.html in two app is it normal works? I worried about that

Comment: I've added an alternative solution, you can try that out if possible